# How to clear z-index rule in the last div?

Tags: css, z-index

I have the following problem: I'm working on this site and using a picture as a background of 1 div. Inside this div I have another 2 dives - logo and navigation. 
Last /outside of the div with the picture/ is the footer, whos background must be other color, not the picture. I set the css to the div with the picture like this :

```
#background{
  position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
   display: block;
}
```

Here is the html :

```
  <div id="pic">
    <img id="background" src="picture.jpg">
    <div class="row" id="logo">
   </div>
  <div class="row" id="example-menu">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="footer">
  <div class="medium-3 columns medium-offset-1" id="worktime">РАБОТНО ВРЕМЕ: </br> ПОНЕДЕЛНИК-ПЕТЪК </br> 08:30-19:00ч.</div>
  <div class="medium-8 columns"></div>
</div>
```

But the problem is that the footer also goes over the div with the picture and my design is not like this... I need to keep the whole picture to be seen.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Instead of saying I have this on that, why dont u just put the simplified version of your HTML ?

Comment: The [initial value for `z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index#Summary) is `auto`.  I'm not sure that's what you need for this situation, but setting `z-index:auto` is the correct way to reset `z-index`.  Please provide your markup for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

Instead of using `<img>`, put the background using CSS

**HTML**

```
<div id="pic">
    <div class="row" id="logo"></div>
    <div class="row" id="example-menu"></div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="footer">
    The footer content
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#pic{
    background: url( 'picture.jpg' ) no-repeat;
}
```

## Option 2

Use **fixed height** for the parent div, `#pic` in this case:
**HTML**

```
<div id="pic">
    <img id="background" src="picture.jpg">
    <div class="row" id="logo"></div>
    <div class="row" id="example-menu"></div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="footer">
    The footer content
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#pic{
    position: relative;
    height: 100px; /* This should be the height of the background image */
}
#background{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

## Option 3

You may use `position:absolute` for the `.row`s instead:

```css
#pic{ position: relative; }
.row{ position: absolute; top: 0; z-index: 99; }
```

```html
  <div id="pic">
    <img id="background" src="https://placehold.it/200x100">
    <div class="row" id="logo">This is logo</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
     The footer content
  </div>
```

Comment: It's not an option - picture is loading much slower and the background is flashing...

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, but the design is responsive and looks wierd when on small sreens... really wondered if possible to just simply put the footer below the pic... :(

Comment: very kind of you, really appriciate it ... still not working, everything went below the pic ... see when you run the code snippet - looks the same ...

Comment: @pantofche I am sure, this is the desired output. please refresh the page and run the snippet.

Comment: OMG YES! May be I had a problem with the browswer after refreshing non stop ! Thanks so so much !!!

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with the z-index of the div containing the image and the div containing the footer.

the easiest solution is to put the footer after the div with your content. The only time z-index should come into play is if you are trying to put items on top of the image for effect.

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
  <div id="nav">
      <span>NAV</span>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="footer">
  <span>FOOTER</span>
</div>
```

you can easily add the footer in the container, attach at the bottom as well.
see if this example helps:
https://plnkr.co/edit/GDfzul2qKApw6JGhQSbb?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, but the footer is not inside the div with the picture. And yes - I need two divs over the image for effect :(

Comment: i updated the link, the footer and nav are inside. the Footer is attached at the bottom, and the container is set to 100vh. check it : https://plnkr.co/edit/GDfzul2qKApw6JGhQSbb?p=preview